# How to add custom tableviewcell separator?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiview

I'd like to add custom tableviewcell separator like this

------------cell-----------

---custom sperator---

------------cell-----------

---custom sperator---

I tried that

1. add uiview below cell in storyboard and connect

   ```
   @IBOutlet weak var sperator: UIView!
   ```
2. addcode in cellForRow cellForRowAtIndexPath

   ```
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPathindexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MainListCell",forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MainTableViewCell

   let list = List(index: indexPath.row)


   cell.titleLabel.text = list.title!
   cell.titleIcon.image = list.icon!
   cell.detailTitleLabel.text = list.detailtitle!
   cell.coinCountLabel.text = "X0"
   cell.addSubview(self.sperator)

   return cell
   }
   ```

but, I can see UIView :(

Comment: Why not just use a different cell type for your separator row - increase the `numberOfRowsInSection` value accordingly and then return the right kind of cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks! But I can fix different way. cell.constent.addSubview(sperator)

Comment: Just make sure you don't add the separator again when you re-use the cell

Answer (score 0):

If you change one code, you can see sperator line

```
cell.contentView.caddSubview(self.sperator)
```